# How to add custom menu after sub-Window menu in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: menu, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a sub-menu under the *"Window"* menu and I want to add my custom menu under it.

I can add my custom menu under *"Window"* menu with menuContribution's **LocationURI:menu:window?after=additions**.

The problem is that sub-menu is generated on ActionBarAdvisor class with this lines

```
@Override
protected void fillWindowMenu(IMenuManager windowMenu) {
    IWorkbenchWindow window = getActionBarConfigurer().getWindowConfigurer().getWindow();

    windowMenu.add(new GroupMarker(IWorkbenchActionConstants.WB_START));

    IMenuManager perspectiveMenu = new MenuManager(
            lineer.toplulastirma.Messages.ToplulastirmaActionBarAdvisor_4,
            ContributionItemFactory.PERSPECTIVES_SHORTLIST.getId());
    perspectiveMenu.add(ContributionItemFactory.PERSPECTIVES_SHORTLIST.create(window));
    windowMenu.add(perspectiveMenu);

    IMenuManager viewMenu = new MenuManager(lineer.toplulastirma.Messages.ToplulastirmaActionBarAdvisor_5,
                ContributionItemFactory.VIEWS_SHORTLIST.getId());
    viewMenu.add(ContributionItemFactory.VIEWS_SHORTLIST.create(window));
    windowMenu.add(viewMenu);
    windowMenu.add( new Separator());
}
```

So I don't know how to access its **id** to edit my *LocationURI*.

I tried these:

**menu:window?after=lineer.toplulastirma.Messages.ToplulastirmaActionBarAdvisor_5**

**menu:lineer.toplulastirma.Messages.ToplulastirmaActionBarAdvisor_5?after=additions**

**menu:viewMenu?after=additions**

**menu:window?after=viewMenu**

They didn't work.

Comment: Can you please post the whole method this code is from? This will make it easier to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I post the whole code which is generating window menu